# Five ordered names

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**Why is this puzzle linear? Because it's...**

---

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it's...

> ... a straight 10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace.

More specifically

> The five items are films whose directors are written on the "cards" and whose release years are written diagonally in the number grid. The titles include the card names.

The full answers being

> [10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_(1979_film)) Blake Edwards (1979)
>  [Jack Frost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Frost_(1998_film)) Troy Miller (1998)
>  [Queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_(2013_film)) Vikas Bahl (2013)
>  [King Arthur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Arthur_(2004_film)) Antoine Fuqua (2004)
>  [Ace Ventura: Pet Detective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_Ventura:_Pet_Detective) Tom Shadyac (1994)

Comment: Indeed it is, nice job!

Comment: @Prim3numbah is there a reason to put the rot13(Qvntbany) element in the puzzle? Seems like an arbitrary factor that is a bit out of place

Comment: @CatProgrammer It was just there to make the years a bit harder to detect

Comment: Can you check the number for Miller in your answer? It looks one off.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh rot13(Vg'f pbeerpg nppbeqvat gb VZQO naq gur dhrfgvba. Abgr gung gurer vf n svyz sebz n  lrne rneyvre bs gur fnzr anzr, ohg abg qverpgrq ol Gebl Zvyyre.)

Comment: Are you sure it's correct according the question? To me it still looks off by one. rot13(gur obggbz evtug pryy vf rvtug - abg avar)

Comment: Oh it was [changed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/122325/revisions). Looking good now